# getX() and getY() for mouse Click event is returning non-integers with gwt on Mac Chrome

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, gwt

Mac Pro Mavericks 10.9, Chrome 30.0.1599.101, GWT 2.5.1, Tomcat 7.0.42

The following gwt code prints out non-integer values for the first two lines (!!), the next 4 seem to always print whole numbers (as expected)...

```
public class EntryPt implements EntryPoint
{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MacChrome");

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel();
        panel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "5px solid red");
        panel.setPixelSize(500, 500);

        panel.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "" + event.getX());
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "" + event.getY());
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "" + event.getClientX());
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "" + event.getClientY());
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "" + event.getScreenX());
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "" + event.getScreenY());
            }
        }, ClickEvent.getType());

        RootPanel.get().add(panel);
    }
}
```

On the same machine/browser/etc, the following all print integers...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>Mouse Test</TITLE>

<SCRIPT>
    function initialise() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("mydiv");
        elem.addEventListener("click", doMouseClick, false);
    }

    function doMouseClick(e) {
        var evt = e ? e : window.event;
        var clickX = 0, clickY = 0;

        if ((evt.clientX || evt.clientY) && document.body
                && document.body.scrollLeft != null) {
            clickX = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            clickY = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        if ((evt.clientX || evt.clientY) && document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat'
                && document.documentElement
                && document.documentElement.scrollLeft != null) {
            clickX = evt.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            clickY = evt.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        if (evt.pageX || evt.pageY) {
            clickX = evt.pageX;
            clickY = evt.pageY;
        }

        alert(evt.type.toUpperCase() + ' mouse event:' + '\n pageX = ' + clickX
                + '\n pageY = ' + clickY + '\n clientX = ' + evt.clientX
                + '\n clientY = ' + evt.clientY + '\n screenX = ' +     evt.screenX
                + '\n screenY = ' + evt.screenY)
    }

    function doMouseClick2(e) {
        var evt = e ? e : window.event;
        var clickX = 0, clickY = 0;

        if ((evt.clientX || evt.clientY) && document.body
                && document.body.scrollLeft != null) {
            clickX = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            clickY = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        if ((evt.clientX || evt.clientY) && document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat'
                && document.documentElement
                && document.documentElement.scrollLeft != null) {
            clickX = evt.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            clickY = evt.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        if (evt.pageX || evt.pageY) {
            clickX = evt.pageX;
            clickY = evt.pageY;
        }

        alert(evt.type.toUpperCase() + '2 mouse event:' + '\n pageX = '
                + clickX + '\n pageY = ' + clickY + '\n clientX = '
                + evt.clientX + '\n clientY = ' + evt.clientY + '\n     screenX = '
                + evt.screenX + '\n screenY = ' + evt.screenY)
    }
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<body onload="initialise()">
    <div id="mydiv">CLICK ME!</div>
    <div id="mydiv" onclick="doMouseClick2(event)">ALSO CLICK ME!</div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

I tried the same thing on a MacBook Pro we have with the same version of Chrome and everything worked fine (ie. event.getX() and getY() were returning ints).  I'm not a Mac, web or javascript expert - and am new to gwt.  I tried using Chrome's developer tools to trace where the decimal numbers were coming from but wasn't able to.  Can someone suggest a way to troubleshoot / track this down?  Is it a Mac OS thing, browser extensions (the tester says he hasn't installed any), something else?

The problem comes in when we try to use restygwt to make calls to the server with mouse coordinates that we expect to be ints but that get passed as floats and then resteasy throws an exception on parseInt attempting to parse the url.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I just tried increasing the zoom on Chrome Windows and was able to reproduce the issue so that seems to be exactly it - as Paul mentioned.  What does one do in this case?  event.getX() is supposed to return an int - but apparently doesn't when things are scaled.  Is this a known issue?  Should I post another question.  I'll see what I can find.

So far, just this:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6130

Comment: Is the client's browser zooming/otherwise scaling the page?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure - I will check on that. Thanks for the comment.